# Leaflet issue related to svg layer ordering

Tags: javascript, reactjs, svg, leaflet, react-leaflet

In my leaflet application I am using both canvas and svg renderers.
Canvas renderer is used for markers and svg for polygon.
But because of this i am unable to order the svg rendered polygon layers using `layer.bringToBack()` method.
Reason why I want polygon layer to back is shown in below image.

Polygon above markers

[image]

Polygon covers my markers making them unclickable I want polygon below my markers as foll image.

Polygon below marker

[image]

In html this is how the layers are arranged, all canvas and html elements.

HTML code

[image]

Please suggest me a suitable solution for my issue

Comment: @starball the given image is to indicate how html code in rendered in browser by leaflet

Comment: I'm talking about the image of the HTML taken from your browser devtools though (the third screenshot- not the first two)

Comment: @starball ok i got you

Comment: One solution would be to generate all your markers on the last layer of the svg.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a new map pane and add the markers to that pane: https://leafletjs.com/reference.html#map-pane

```
map.createPane('canvasMarkers'); //https://leafletjs.com/reference.html#map-createpane

var canvas = L.canvas({
    pane: 'canvasMarkers'
})

L.circleMarker(map.getCenter(), {renderer: canvas}).addTo(map);
```

```
.leaflet-canvasMarkers-pane{
   z-index: 600;
}
```

or just use the image marker pane:

```
var canvas = L.canvas({
    pane: 'markerPane'
})

L.circleMarker(map.getCenter(), {renderer: canvas}).addTo(map);
```

https://plnkr.co/edit/gVuJvUw7mCVNa6Xj